# How to show a number pattern in C++

Tags: c++

How can I show the following pattern?

```
1 2 3 4 5
  1 2 3 4
    1 2 3
      1 2
        1
```

Comment: I think you just did, there at your question

Comment: I aint that young to do homework.. :)

Comment: Geeze -- here I was working on this really nifty one that generated the pattern in a template metaprogram, and then the question got closed before I could finish and post it!

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
cout << "1 2 3 4 5" << "\n";
cout << "  1 2 3 4" << "\n";
cout << "    1 2 3" << "\n";
cout << "      1 2" << "\n";
cout << "        1" << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

printf("1 2 3 4 5\n  1 2 3 4\n    1 2 3\n      1 2\n        1\n");

That'll be four peanuts please.

Comment: Thats the C way. Ahhh clever... trying to trick him ehh?

Answer (score 0):

`#`include `<iostream>`

void pattern(const int N) {
    for (int i=N;i>0;i--) {
        for (int j=i;j
            std::cout << "  ";
        for (int j=0;j
            std::cout << j+1 << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(void){
    pattern(5);
    return 0;
}

Comment: Nothing wrong with homework questions.